# Is there any way to export PDF file with markup, from BIM360 Docs 'Project Files' Directory using API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We are able to export files with markup from the Plan folder using BIM360 Docs **API**. But our requirement is to **export PDF files with markup** from **Project files**. Is there any way?

Comment: yes, as API help document mentioned, it supports Plan and and sub-folders only. I am checking with engineer team on whether there is any workaround or any new API is on the roadmap

Comment: our engineer team told me Export PDF API has applied with Project Files folder, while the API document has not updated. Sorry for this. I tested to include markup, but it looks no markup in  the exported PDF. I will need more time to verify

Comment: I missed the API can only works with public or unarchived markup. So, the API can works with the PDF in Project Files folder. We will update the API help accordingly. Could you give it a test and send your feedback?

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it in postman and it works for 
public doc from the 'project files' top folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can export a PDF document with markup from the project files directory. As  Xiaodong Liang said markup required to be published not private and will work for both plan and project files folder.

API link: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/export-pdf-from-docs/